# Permission name to view manage display page

Tags: 8

I want to programatically use a permission to give user access to the manage display page. Does anybody know the name of that permission?
'administer content types' only gets me far as to edit the content type.

Answer (score 0):

The route definitions for the *Manage display* pages are added from [`RouteSubscriber::alterRoutes()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21field_ui%21src%21Routing%21RouteSubscriber.php/function/RouteSubscriber%3A%3AalterRoutes/8.9.x), a class implemented from the *Field UI* module. The relevant code is the following one.

```php
$route = new Route("{$path}/display", [
  '_entity_form' => 'entity_view_display.edit',
  '_title' => 'Manage display',
  'view_mode_name' => 'default',
] + $defaults, [
  '_field_ui_view_mode_access' => 'administer ' . $entity_type_id . ' display',
], $options);
```

The permission the users need to have to access those pages is *administer $entity_type_id display*. Since there is a page for every fieldable entity defined, the permission changes basing on the entity for which that page is shown. For nodes, that permission is *administer node display*.

Those permissions are defined from the *Field UI* module in [`FieldUiPermissions::fieldPermissions()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21field_ui%21src%21FieldUiPermissions.php/function/FieldUiPermissions%3A%3AfieldPermissions/8.9.x). A module using them should add the *Field UI* module to its dependencies.